# db2 export with table names

Tags: csv, db2, export

Can someone tell me if in db2 db is possible to export a table with column names included to CSV?

Example:

```
column1;column2;...;
1234435;asdasda;...;
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation for the [EXPORT command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html), I'm guessing you can't automatically put in the column names in the exported file. You can, however, specify which columns to export and what order to place them in.

Comment: true... you can do this with select c1, c2,... or with method n... any ideas how to include table names... not necesarily with export :)